# Android stack of fragments view

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, fragment, android-custom-view

Now i'm developing an app in which one of the functions is showing some users profiles. This profiles designed as stack of fragment or views. Each fragment or view is under previous fragment or view and can be swiped with some animation. You can see this on image:

[image]

But i don't really know how to do this. Maybe there are some libs that help me to do this thing or any ideas ? Thx

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-carousel-view/ ?

Comment: like this https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards but i dont know about custom layout in card i'll test this

Comment: this library is that i want but it don't allow users templates, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a great Fragment Transaction library https://github.com/DesarrolloAntonio/FragmentTransactionExtended

You can also use FragmentTransactions like replace, add, remove etc.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: i know about fragment transactions, i dont know how to write view like on img